# C++:List iterators are pointing to the wrong location

Tags: c++, list, iterator

**Warning. Huge question length.**

Hi.
So, I'm trying to write a program that takes a sequence of n points in the xy plane as input (a simple polygon), along with a line ax + by =c, and outputs a list of polygons that the line divides the original one into.

So i define the following :

```
      struct point
    {
        public:
        float x, y;
        list <point>::iterator it;//if the point is an intersection point, this points to the position in the other list in class polygon where the point is located. This value is not defined for a point which is only in list pts (see class polygon)
        bool operator <(point );
        int pair;//paired intersection points will have identical pairing values 
        int poly;//poly shows if it is part of polygon or not
        point intersection( point, point, line);//returns the point of intersection

         void output();
         };

    class polygon
    {
        public:
        int n;
        list <point> pts;//stores points of original polygon as well as intersection points
        list <point> intr;// stores intersection points
        void init_it();//initialises iterators of points present in original polygon
        void init_pair();//initialises "pair" for consecutive points as 1,1,0,0,1,1...
//This allows pairing up of consecutive points the line intersects for convenient traversal of the polygon in one direction only
        void intersects(line);//solves every relevant side of polygon with the line to get a list of relevant points
        void output();
        polygon()
        {n=0;}
    };

    class line
    {
        public:
        float a,b,c;    
        float eval(point p);
    };
```

Look at the `intersects()` and `main()` functions here.

```
void polygon::intersects(line l)
{
    list <point>::iterator i=pts.begin();
    list <point>::iterator j=i;

    while(true)
    {   
        j++;
        if (j==pts.end())
               j=pts.begin();


                       if(intersect(*i,*j,l))
           {
            point p=intersection(*i,*j,l);
            pts.insert(j,p);
            intr.push_front(p);
            i++;
            list <point>::iterator k=intr.begin();
            (*i).it=k;
            (*k).it=i;
            (*k).poly=(*i).poly=0;
        }
    i=j;
}

}
```

(Snippet from `main()`)

```
while(p.n>0)//flag= new beginning, beg= current beginning
    { 
        //Initialise stuff
        while(i!=beg)   
        {


            t.pts.push_back(*i);
            if( (*i).poly==1 )//point from original polygon 
            {
            //do stuff, increment i
            }
            else if(((*i).poly)==0)
            {
                //DO something



                list <point>:: iterator j= (*i).it;
                list <point>:: iterator k1=j,k2=j;
                if( j==p.intr.begin() )
                {
                    j++;
                }
                else if(j==end)
                {
                    j--;
                }
                else
                {// Gets into an infinite loop here


                    k1--;
                    k2++;
                    if((*j).pair==(*k1).pair)
                    {

                        j--;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                t.pts.push_back(*j);
                i=(*j).it;// This line is supposed to set i to the next iterator in the "intr" list, but it doesnt change!


            }
            else
            i++;
        }

    output.push_back(t);
    }
```

The problem here is in the `main()` function. When i write `i=(*j).it`, it does not return the value i want it to. The iterator seems to be pointing to the same point, leading to an infinite loop. I can't find any problem with it.

Here's a sample test case with its answer:

Test case:

```
12
0 0 0 5 5 5 5 2 2 2 2 3 4 3 4 4 1 4 1 1 5 1 5 0
1 0 3
```

Answer expected:

```
4
8
0 0 0 5 3 5 3 4 1 4 1 1 3 1 3 0
4
2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2
4
3 0 3 1 5 1 5 0
8
3 2 3 3 4 3 4 4 3 4 3 5 5 5 5 2
```

Note: The *algorithm* i used here seems to work (checked with other people who'd used a similar one), but I seem to have made some mistake in implementing it.

Comment: Well ok, i'll try and edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has a lot of code to review. But, on the other hand, I know that geometric problem perfectly. So I'm going to provide you a solution:

First, classes to hold lines and points (Simplified):

```
struct point_2d
{
    float x , y;

    point_2d( float _x = 0.0f , float _y = 0.0f) : x( _x ) , y( _y ) {}
};


struct line
{
    float a,b,c,d; //ax + by + c = 0

    float relative_position(const point_2d& point) { return a*point.x + b*point.y + c; }
};


using polygon = std::vector<point_2d>;
```

Here is a solution based on STL algorithms (I prefer this):

```
std::pair<polygon,polygon> divide_polygon(const polygon& poly , const line& ln)
{
    polygon up_poly;
    polygon down_poly;

    std::partition_copy( std::begin( poly ) , std::end( poly ) , std::back_inserter( up_poly ) , std::back_inserter( down_poly ) , [](const point_2d& point) { return ln.relative_position( point ) >= 0; });

    return std::make_pair( up_poly , down_poly );
}
```

Note that I closed up my answer to the two first lines of your question (The abstract description of the problem). This code works perfectly, and takes advantage of STL (Algorithms, containers, etc). **I'm not giving you the exact answer to your problem. I'm not going to provide you the solution to a online judge problem. Thats YOUR homework**.

Comment: I'm not really interested in a solution to an online judge problem here.
The point is, I'm getting stuck in an infinite loop and i think it's because of conceptual problems in iterator handling.

Comment: @MihirKulkarni Oh, you have deleted the two first lines of your question, the only lines that are a real question, and writted the **worst phrase you could use in a SO question**: ***"Hi. Try to solve this"***, followed by a problem description. Prepare to be downvoted by everybody that read the question

Comment: Well, I'd have thought it was a sufficient and succint enough description.
Let me try again.

Comment: Another alternative to two `std::copy_if` would be a single [`std::partition_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy).